# Finding a particular value in an HTTP response using Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, parsing, substring

I have a little script in Perl, HTTP POST request

```
my $request =  $ua->post( $url, [ 'country' => 10, 'evalprice' => 0 ] );
my $response = $request->content;
```

Now I know that in the response there will be this part, which appears only once

```
:&nbsp;<b>9570&nbsp;USD
```

I want to take only the number 9570 (or whatever it will be), I don't know how to search for

```
:&nbsp;<b>
```

and then just take the part after that and before

```
&nbsp;USD
```

I guess regular expressions will help, but I can't figure out how to use them here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track with the regular expression. You only need one expression, and since your string is straightforward, you don't even need a very complicated one.

```
my $content =~ m/:&nbsp;<b>([.\d]+)&nbsp;USD/;
my $price = $1;
```

The `m//` is the matching operator. Together wil `=~` it tells Perl to do a regular expression to your variable `$content`. We have a capture group (`()`) that contains the price, and it's contents will go into `$1`. The `[.\d+]` is a group of characters. The dot is just a dot (your price might have cents), and the `\d` means all digits (`0`-`9`). The `+` says there may be lots of these characters, but at least one.

- Try it out at http://rubular.com
- Read more on Regular Expressions in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)
- Have a look at [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) if you want to do more to the website

Answer (score 1):

Use code like this (removing HTML entities is nice, but optional):

```
use HTML::Entities;

my $content = ":&nbsp;<b>9570&nbsp;USD";
my $decoded = decode_entities($content); # replace &nbsp; to spaces
my ($price) = ($decoded =~ /<b>(\d+)\s*USD/);
print "price = $price\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to parse HTML is with the help of a proper CPAN module. But a simple alternative (if the response is simple) may be this;

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = ":&nbsp;<b>9570&nbsp;USD";

if( $str =~ m/:&nbsp;<b>(\d+)&nbsp;/ ) {
   print $1, "\n";
}
```

I have used a regular expression, and the number is at `$1` when a match is found.